# Python requests on Instagram media link returns Not Found error

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I have this function in Python to get media id of the post from its URL provided:

```
def get_media_id(self):
    req = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url={}'.format(self.txtUrl.text()))
    media_id = req.json()['media_id']
    return media_id
```

When I open the result URL in the browser it returns data but in the code the result is "404 not found"
For example consider this link:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/B05bitzp15CE8e3Idcl4DAb8fjsfxOsSUYvkDY0/
```

When I put it in the url the result is:
[image]

But when I run the same in this function it returns 404 error

Comment: What is the content of `self.txtUrl.text()`?

Comment: The URL of the media which I want to get its media id

Comment: Okay but do you have an example that is failing like you describe that you can share here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running your code and assuming that `self.txtUrl.text()` there is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is that you are trying to get access to a media id of a **private account** without the access token.

The reason that you are able to open that link in the browser is due to the fact that you are likely logged into that account or are following it. To use the method you have given, you would need a public instagram post, for example try setting `txtUrl.text() = https://www.instagram.com/p/fA9uwTtkSN/`. Your code should work just fine.

The problem is that your GET request doesn't have any authorisation token to gain access to the post. Other people have written answers to how to get the `media_id` if you have the access token here: [Where do I find the Instagram media ID of a image (having access token and following the image owner)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158362/where-do-i-find-the-instagram-media-id-of-a-image-having-access-token-and-follo)